# Error Template Layout

Tags: wpf, templates, layout

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultErrorTemplate">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <DKMS:WarningImage Margin="10,0,0,0"
                               DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                               Notification="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner,
                                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
        </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And in text box style:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultErrorTemplate}" />
```

[image]

The question is how do I force the layout update that is triggered by mouse over? It is also triggered by a MessageBox.

Comment: Do **not** post code as an image.

Comment: Is this part of a `Validation.ErrorTemplate`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. It's the whole Validation.ErrorTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an ErrorTemplate, then you display it by telling the binding system that the binding is invalid.  Typically this is done through the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.  But again, this assumes that you're using some sort of binding on the `TextBox`, typically the `Text` property.

Here's a blog post about the topic: http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/04/17/wpf-validation-with-attributes-and-idataerrorinfo-interface-in-mvvm.aspx

It sounds, though, like you are using "event based" programming, and so I don't think you want to use `Validation.ErrorTemplate`, it sounds like you really want to do some custom adorners.  You might want to check out this CodeProject post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML on that topic.

Comment: No, it is not event based. And yes, it is Text property of TextBox. The problem is:

1) The binding receives an exception from source (I'm using an exception validation rule). 
2) While the error template DOES show up, it is at wrong location. It seems like the layout of TextBox doesn't get updated, or something like that. Once I hover my mouse over an element (or open a dialog window like MessageBox and close it), it probably gets revalidated and it becomes fine. Now I want to trigger this behavior (revalidation) manually. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Solved. Marking an answer because it's the only one. This is what helped me: http://immortalratblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/weird-solutions-ho-can-i-force-wpf.html